# Summation series formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

What will be the summation formula for the following series:

```
1+1/2+1/3+...............+1/n
```

Also, I am looking for a place online where I can get all list of such forumals, where I can get one please? Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Answer (score 2):

There is no closed form for the $n$-th harmonic number. This was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451558/how-to-find-the-sum-of-this-series-1-frac12-frac13-frac14-do), as well.