# Sum of $1/n+1/(n-2) + 1/(n-4) + \cdots $

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How does one calculate $$\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n-2} + \frac{1}{n-4} \cdots $$
where this series continues until denominator is no longer positive?

$n$ is some fixed constant positive integer.

Comment: What are the limits of summation? From n=1 to infinity?

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: $n$ isn't even is it?

Answer (score 1):

In the case that $n$ is even, this is a harmonic series

$\sum_{i=1}^{n/2} \frac{1}{2i}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n/2} \frac{1}{i}$.

There is no analytical solution for this sum, but the estimate

$\frac{1}{2}\ln(n/2+1)< \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n/2} \frac{1}{i} < \frac{1}{2}\ln(n/2)+1$

holds. If $n$ is odd, you get similar estimates using

$\int_0^{\frac{n+1}2}\frac{1}{2i-1}\ di\leq \sum_{i=1}^{(n+1)/2}\frac{1}{2i-1}\leq \int_1^{\frac{n+1}2+1}\frac{1}{2i-1}\ di$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will not be simple.

[How to find the sum of this series : $1+\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451558/how-to-find-the-sum-of-this-series-1-frac12-frac13-frac14-do)

If one could find a simple expression for your sum, one could also find a simple expression for harmonic numbers and vice versa.