# How would i put this into polynomial equation really struggling ive tried alot

Tags: measure-theory, polynomials, summation, education

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j} $$
given in the question $n>0$
I've tried inputting numbers for n to get $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}......\frac{1}{n}$ but i dont know how to put this in an equation form i know that stuff exists like $\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$ for $k^2$ but nothing for $\frac{1}{k^2}$?

Comment: See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). I don't think there is a nice expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the sum of this series : $1+\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451558/how-to-find-the-sum-of-this-series-1-frac12-frac13-frac14-do)

Comment: The formula you quote for the sum of $k^2$ in fact is for $k^3$. You will not find a similar simple form for the harmonic series.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H_n=1+\frac12+...+\frac1n$. There is no polynomial $f$ such that $f(n)=H_n$ for all $n$. One way of seeing this is that $H_n$ grows slower and slower as $n\to\infty$, but polynomials grow faster and faster as $n\to\infty$. Specifically, we have $H_{n+1}-H_n\to 0$, but if $f$ is a non-constant polynomial, then $f(n+1)-f(n)$ is also a polynomial, and either converges to plus or minus infinity if $\deg f\geq 2$, or is constant if $\deg f=1$.