# Sum of a (finite) hyperharmonic series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, power-series

For some $k < \infty$, and $p \in (0,1)$, consider the following sum:
$S_k = \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n^p}$.

What is a closed form expression for $S_k$?

Comment: It may worth have a look at Hurwitz's zeta function.

Comment: @KemonoChen: [Hurwitz's zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) is also infinite, check [generalized harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalizations).

Comment: @Tianlalu You can make a subtraction from Riemann's zeta function.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found the answer below helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451558/how-to-find-the-sum-of-this-series-1-frac12-frac13-frac14-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any closed form, but there are some good approximations. The easiest way would be to approximate this sum with an integral:
$$\sum_{n=1}^kn^{-p}\approx1+\int_1^k x^{-p}dx=1+\left.\frac1{1-p}x^{1-p}\right\rvert^k_0=1+\frac{k^{1-p}}{1-p}.$$