# Proving $H_n − 1 \leq \ln{n} \leq H_n − \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, summation, proof-writing, mean-value-theorem

How do I prove $$H_n − 1 \leq \ln{n} \leq H_n − \frac{1}{n}$$ where, $$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}$$

I was trying to do this using $f'(k + 1) ≤ f(k + 1) − f(k) ≤ f'(k)$ (proven using Lagrange's mean value theorem) and using the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}\leq\ln{n}$.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/451668

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\int_k^{k+1}\frac{1}{k+1}dx <\int_k^{k+1}\frac{1}{x}dx <\int_k^{k+1}\frac{1}{k}dx$$